# Use extended class in place of base class

Tags: java, class, extends, type-mismatch

Java 1.6. I have extended a class to include some methods. Now I would like to use the extended class in place of the base class. However, the classes that could use the base class cannot "recognize" the extended class. What is the (recommended) fix?

I know this has been asked many times in different flavors, but I can't get it!

Example- Extend class `SAMRecord` and use `SAMRecordExt` afterwords:

```
public class SAMRecordExt extends SAMRecord{

    public SAMRecordExt(SAMFileHeader header) {
        super(header);
    }       

}
```

Now, while this works:

```
SAMRecord rec= sam.iterator().next();
```

This gives me a compilation error

```
SAMRecordExt recext= sam.iterator().next();
>>> Type mismatch: cannot convert from SAMRecord to SAMRecordExt
```

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't work either (runtime error):

```
SAMRecordExt recext= (SAMRecordExt) sam.iterator().next();
>>> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: htsjdk.samtools.SAMRecord cannot be cast to markDupsByStartEnd.SAMRecordExt
at markDupsByStartEnd.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

How can I make the extended class work where the base class worked?

**EDIT**: More detail about the classes I'm using. `sam` object comes from

```
SamReaderFactory sf = SamReaderFactory.makeDefault();
SamReader sam= sf.open(new File(insam));
```

Full documentation is https://samtools.github.io/htsjdk/javadoc/htsjdk/index.html

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of variable "sam"  in the above code

Comment: It seems that that class was meant to be used with the super class, meaning: the author knew about the super class, and needs the functionality provided in that. Now, the problem is, when you try to do that cast: every instance of the child class is an instance of the super class, but not every instance of the super class is an instance of the child class.

Comment: It seems to me that you aren't running the code you think you're running, or rather you aren't compiling the code you posted. You should not get any compile errors provided `SAMRecordExt extends SAMRecord` as per the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is:

```
sam.iterator().next()
```

returns a `SAMRecord` object

Which means

```
SAMRecordExt recext= sam.iterator().next();
```

will not work because a super class can not assigned to a sub class variable.

The general problem is that the subclass is more specific than the super class
thats why you can't assign a super class object to a subClass variable because the super class doen't know the things which the sub class needs to know.

On the other hand the subclass knows the details of the super class and some more details which means you are able to assign a sub class object to a super class variable.

**Solution for the Problem:** *(EDIT)*

Normally you extend the class and are able to override the iterator method and return a well constructed iterator of the type you wish.

But the Problem I see here is that the factory creates your obj of type SamReader which you use to iterate over the SamRecords

*SO* 
-> you must extends the factory to return other type of SamReader and iterate later over your wished record types see the

Source code of the Factory class:

https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/blob/master/src/java/htsjdk/samtools/SamReaderFactory.java

Comment: HI- When you say "use the SAMRecord type for the variable", doesn't this defeat the point of extending the class?

Comment: Thanks! About "override the iterator method in the sub class" any chance you could post a synopsis of the code to use?

Comment: Problem i see is that the factory creates your obj of type SamReder which you use to iterate over the SamRecords -> you must extends the factory to return other type of SamReader and iterate later over other record types see the https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/blob/master/src/java/htsjdk/samtools/SamReaderFactory.java

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. So the problem and solution is in SamReader not in my SAMRecordExt.

Comment: Correct, i didnt realized it before because i overread the declaration of the sam variable: SamReader sam= sf.open(new File(insam));